# C++ issue with value over write

Tags: c++, esp32

I am developing a code using PlatformIO for ESP32, in which I am taking data from mobile App over BLE on my ESP32 module & need to use that data as SSID & password to connect with WiFi.

Currently, when I am writing data on a single characteristic & extracting SSID & password using ">=" as a identifier from a written data. When I am passing the data to "ssid" & "password" in my code it parse same value in "ssid" as well as in "password" variable.

Below is my code snippet:

```
class MyssidCallbacks1: public BLECharacteristicCallbacks {
    void onWrite(BLECharacteristic *pWiFiSSIDCharacteristic) {
      std::string rxValue1 = pWiFiSSIDCharacteristic->getValue();
      pWiFiSSIDCharacteristic->setValue(rxValue1);
      delay(10);
      if (rxValue1.length() > 0){
        char* ssid1 = "mobilenet";
        char* password1 = "password";
        Serial.println("----------");
        Serial.print("Received Value: ");
        for (int j = 0; j < rxValue1.length(); j++)
          Serial.print(rxValue1[j]);



          delay(10);
          char cstr[rxValue1.size() + 1];
          strcpy(cstr,rxValue1.c_str());

          std::string delimiter = ">=";
          size_t pos = 0;
          std::string token;
          while ((pos = rxValue1.find(delimiter)) != std::string::npos) {
          token = rxValue1.substr(0, pos);
          Serial.println("TOKEN ");
          char cstr0[token.size() + 1];
          strcpy(cstr0,token.c_str());
          Serial.println(cstr0);
          rxValue1.erase(0, pos + delimiter.length());
          ssid1 = cstr0;
          Serial.println(ssid1);
          Serial.println(password1);
          }
          char cstr00[rxValue1.size() + 1];
          strcpy(cstr00,rxValue1.c_str());
          Serial.println(cstr00);

          password1 = cstr00;
          delay(5);

          Serial.println("Final Value is: ");
          Serial.println(ssid1);
          Serial.println(password1);
          Serial.println("------------");
          delay(5);
      }
    }
};


OUTOUT:
09:47:15.195 -> ----------
09:47:15.195 -> Received Value: $>=1277 
09:47:15.195 -> TOKEN 
09:47:15.195 -> $
09:47:15.195 -> $
09:47:15.195 -> password
09:47:15.195 -> 1277
09:47:15.195 -> Final Value is: 
09:47:15.195 -> 1277
09:47:15.195 -> 1277
09:47:15.195 -> ------------
```

In above code I need to have "ssid" value as "$" ans "password" value as "1277". Please help

Thanks you

Comment: What did You find while debugging the code?

Comment: Hi Robert, in above code snippet I am reading data from "rxVlalue1", when I am interpreting data and writing value from "cstr0" in "ssid" it takes correct value as "$" but after that when I update the value of "cstr00" into "password" field, "ssid" field also get updated with the same value as "password" field is having which is "1277". My string is "$>=1277" from which in "ssid" I need to have value as "$" & in "password" I need to have value as "1277". Please guide.

Comment: Why are You sometimes using char arrays and other times string?